# Small arrow in CSS

Tags: html, css

How do we create this small arrow (see image attached) in css?

I am using a regular > (closing >) arrow, but that does not quite work

[image]

Comment: Try with this character entity: &gt; or this: &rsaquo;

Comment: Do you have UTF-8 in HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using font-awesome. There are many icons , and it's really helpful.
For your case it's used http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/chevron-right/

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
```

You can use font-awesome via CDN (Content Delivery Network) or just download it.